# Find or create nested attributes in a polymorphic join table, in one transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

**Background**

I want to save skills on different types of objects. Typically, a user can have a project or experience, and tag it with different skills etc. Ruby , python or Excel. These skills are global and used across the various possible objects that are "skillable".

The problem consists of three models:

1. Project - contains info about the project
2. Skill - contains the name of the skill
3. SkillObject - join table between skill and projects
   (polymorphic)

Please look at this [ER-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF8eb.png) for a more detailed picture.

---

**The problem**

When I create or update a project, I also want the skills to be added in the same transaction, just by sending the names of the skills from the front-end.

I want a kind of find_or_create_by to avoid duplicate skills. At the same time, validations must ensure that two identical skills cannot be put on the same project (*skill_object.rb*) and that the skill name cannot be zero (*skill.rb*)

The wanted behavior is if the validation of skills is not successful, then either the project nor the skills are stored in the database. If you enter two different skill names and one is already in the database, the one that exists should be found and connected to the project, and the other created and so connected through the join table, if not validations fails.

---

**project.rb**

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  include Skillable
  [...] 
end
```

**skill_object.rb**

```rb
class SkillObject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill, inverse_of: :skill_objects
  belongs_to :skillable, polymorphic: true

  delegate :delete_if_empty_skill_objects, to: :skill
  after_destroy :delete_if_empty_skill_objects

  # Avoiding duplicates of the same skill
  validates :skill, uniqueness: { scope: :skillable }

end
```

**skill.rb**

```rb
class Skill < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :skill_objects, inverse_of: :skill

  has_many :projects, through: :skill_objects, source: :sectorable, source_type: 'Project'
  has_many :experiences, through: :skill_objects, source: :sectorable, source_type: 'Experience'

  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  def delete_if_empty_skill_objects
    self.destroy if self.skill_objects.empty? and not self.is_global
  end
end
```

I use a concern that is included on the different types of skillable objects:

**concercns/skillable.rb**

```rb
module Skillable

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :skills_attributes
    after_save :set_skills


    # Adding needed relations for skillable objects
    has_many :skill_objects, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }, as: :skillable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :skills, through: :skill_objects


    private
    def set_skills

      # THIS CODE IS THE ONE I AM STRUGGLING WITH


      # Parsing out all the skill names
      skill_names = skills_attributes.pluck(:name)

      # Removing existing skills
      self.skills = []


      # Building new skills
      skill_names.each do |name|
        existing = Skill.find_by(name: name)

        if existing
          self.skills << existing
        else
          self.skills.new(name: name)
        end
      end

      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless self.valid?
      self.skills.each(&:save)
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how I can write the set_skill function in skillable.rb to be able to save and update skills, validate the parent object and the skills, do a rollback if not validated and add the appropriate errors to the project object if it failes?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html? It's made for this.

Comment: The problem I faced when using nested atteibutes were trying to look for an exisiting entry in the database, using the name of the skill. Do you know how an implementation with overriding the autosave or validation method using «find or create by» actually would look like using nested attributes?

Comment: can you post anything on Github? I'm confused by what you are doing. It shouldn't be hard. If the skill exists, then use that, if it doesn't exist then create one, and if that fails, then save nothing. am i understanding correctly?

Comment: The project is not open source, so it is difficult to post anything on Github. 

Yes, that is right @BKSpurgeon! I want to do something like this in GraphQL:

`p = Project.create(name: 'Webpage', skill_attributes: [{name: 'HTML'},{name: 'CSS'}])`

If project or skills failes, then nothing is created and p has errors.

Comment: @DanielKittilsenHenriksen my recommendation would be to extract (or even recreate) those essential models and attributes in a minimal rails app and post it on Github - make it easy for people to solve, and likely, someone will solve it. my two cents.